# Retrieve many XMLType from XMLTYPE variable

Tags: xml, oracle, xmltype, xmltable

I have this XML:

```
<envCFe versao="0.07" xmlns="http://www.fazenda.sp.gov.br/sat">
    <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
    <idLote>4100</idLote>
    <cUF>35</cUF>
    <LoteCFe>
        <CFe>
            <infCFe versao="0.07" versaoDadosEnt="0.07" versaoSB="020100">
            </infCFe>
        </CFe>
        <CFe>
            <infCFe versao="0.07" versaoDadosEnt="0.07" versaoSB="020100">
            </infCFe>
        </CFe>
        <CFe>
            <infCFe versao="0.07" versaoDadosEnt="0.07" versaoSB="020100">
            </infCFe>
        </CFe>
    <dhEnvio>20171106081311</dhEnvio>
    <nserieSAT>000081226</nserieSAT>
</envCFe>
```

And I need to make the node `<CFe>` inside `<LoteCFe` retrieve as many inside a variable declare as `XMLTYPE`

To pass as parameter to another procedure, so for simplify:

```
SELECT
X.nodeCFe
FROM
XMLTABLE(
    '/envCFe/LoteCFe'
    PASSING XMLTYPE(
        '<envCFe versao="0.07" xmlns="http://www.fazenda.sp.gov.br/sat">
        <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
        <idLote>4100</idLote>
        <cUF>35</cUF>
        <LoteCFe>
            <CFe>
                <infCFe versao="0.07" versaoDadosEnt="0.07" versaoSB="020100">
                </infCFe>
            </CFe>
            <CFe>
                <infCFe versao="0.07" versaoDadosEnt="0.07" versaoSB="020100">
                </infCFe>
            </CFe>
            <CFe>
                <infCFe versao="0.07" versaoDadosEnt="0.07" versaoSB="020100">
                </infCFe>
            </CFe>
            <dhEnvio>20171106081311</dhEnvio>
            <nserieSAT>000081226</nserieSAT>
        </LoteCFe>
    </envCFe>'
    )
    COLUMNS
        nodeCFe XMLTYPE PATH 'CFe'
) X
;
```

What I could make wrong to get this result as table?

```
nodeCFe
-------
<CFe><infCFe versao="0.07" versaoDadosEnt="0.07" versaoSB="020100"></infCFe</CFe>
<CFe><infCFe versao="0.07" versaoDadosEnt="0.07" versaoSB="020100"></infCFe</CFe>
<CFe><infCFe versao="0.07" versaoDadosEnt="0.07" versaoSB="020100"></infCFe</CFe>
```

Comment: It isn’t very clear.... what does your query retrun now, and what do you want? Three separate XMLType values?

Answer (score 1):

Your root node declares a namespace, so you need to handle that in your query; you can do that with a default XMLNamespaces clause. You also need the XPath to go down to node you want to extract:

```
SELECT
X.nodeCFe
FROM
XMLTABLE(
    XMLNAMESPACES(default 'http://www.fazenda.sp.gov.br/sat'),
    '/envCFe/LoteCFe/CFe'
    PASSING XMLTYPE(
...
```

With your data:

```
SELECT
X.nodeCFe
FROM
XMLTABLE(
    XMLNAMESPACES(default 'http://www.fazenda.sp.gov.br/sat'),
    '/envCFe/LoteCFe/CFe'
    PASSING XMLTYPE(
        '<envCFe versao="0.07" xmlns="http://www.fazenda.sp.gov.br/sat">
        <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
        <idLote>4100</idLote>
        <cUF>35</cUF>
        <LoteCFe>
            <CFe>
                <infCFe versao="0.07" versaoDadosEnt="0.07" versaoSB="020100">
                </infCFe>
            </CFe>
            <CFe>
                <infCFe versao="0.07" versaoDadosEnt="0.07" versaoSB="020100">
                </infCFe>
            </CFe>
            <CFe>
                <infCFe versao="0.07" versaoDadosEnt="0.07" versaoSB="020100">
                </infCFe>
            </CFe>
            <dhEnvio>20171106081311</dhEnvio>
            <nserieSAT>000081226</nserieSAT>
        </LoteCFe>
    </envCFe>'
    )
    COLUMNS
        nodeCFe XMLTYPE PATH '.'
) X
;
```

gets

```
NODECFE                                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<CFe xmlns="http://www.fazenda.sp.gov.br/sat"><infCFe versao="0.07" versaoDadosE
nt="0.07" versaoSB="020100">
                </infCFe></CFe>

<CFe xmlns="http://www.fazenda.sp.gov.br/sat"><infCFe versao="0.07" versaoDadosE
nt="0.07" versaoSB="020100">
                </infCFe></CFe>

<CFe xmlns="http://www.fazenda.sp.gov.br/sat"><infCFe versao="0.07" versaoDadosE
nt="0.07" versaoSB="020100">
                </infCFe></CFe>
```